# If $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ is a topological ball, is $\partial X$ a topological sphere?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, spheres

Given a set $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ (I am most interested in $n=4$) that is homeomorphic to the $n$-ball $B^n:=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid \|x\|\le 1\}$. Is it true that the boundary $\partial X$ is homeomorphic to the $(n-1)$-sphere $S^{n-1}:=\partial B^n$?

This sounds like an inverse of the [generalized Schönflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations), but I haven't found anything on this.

Comment: Draw two circles on a piece of paper such that one is inside the other and they meet at a single point of tangency. Then the interior  of the crescent shaped region between them is homeomorphic to the disk, but its boundary is the wedge of two circles (not a single circle).

Comment: @AlexS Is it? I can't figure out where the point of tangence is mappes to in the disc by the homeomorphism. If this is a valid counterexample, can you make it into an answer?

Comment: The point of tangency does not belong to the interior of the crescent shaped region.

Comment: @AlexS The interior is not homeomorphic to the *closed* disc that I use in my question.

Comment: Ah, Ok. In that case, see the Alexander Horned Sphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere

Comment: Isn't this a counterexample to the naive formulation of the Schönfliess theorem, not its converse? The boundary is a sphere, right?

Comment: Does this follow from invariance of domain?

Comment: @M.Rumpy You may be right. I am too rusty on topology.

Comment: @Randall I wasn't aware of that! Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @M.Rumpy  I'm not sure that it's right.  I tried to write an argument but I got stuck toward the end.

Answer (score 5):

This follows from invariance of domain.  Let $f:B^n\to X$ be a homeomorphism and let $U$ be the interior of $B^n$.  Then $f(U)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by invariance of domain.  Thus $\partial X\subseteq f(\partial B^n)$.  For the reverse inclusion, if $x$ is in the interior of $X$, then $x$ has a neighborhood in $X$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $f^{-1}(x)$ has a neighborhood in $B^n$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which implies $f^{-1}(x)\in U$ (for instance, by invariance of domain considering $B^n$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  So $\partial X=f(\partial B^n)$ and is homeomorphic to $\partial B^n$ via $f$.

Answer (score 4):

It is true. As Randall suggests in his comment, we can apply the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

We have an embedding $f : B^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(B^n) = X$. The restriction of $f$ to the open unit ball $\mathring B^n$ is a continuous injection, thus $X' = f(\mathring B^n)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. Since $X' \subset X$, we have $X' \subset \operatorname{int} X  =$ topological interior of $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f^{-1} : X \to B^n$ be the inverse of $f$. The map $\phi : \operatorname{int} X \to \mathbb R^n, \phi(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, is a continuous injection, thus $\phi(\operatorname{int} X)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. Since $\phi(\operatorname{int} X) \subset B^n$, we see that $\phi(\operatorname{int} X) = f^{-1}(\operatorname{int} X) \subset \operatorname{int} B^n = \mathring B^n$. Thus $\operatorname{int} X \subset X'$.

Hence $\operatorname{int} X = X'$ which implies $\partial X = X \setminus \operatorname{int} X = X \setminus X' = f(S^{n-1})$, i.e. $\partial X \approx S^{n-1}$.